# List mapped network drives for particular user

Tags: windows, powershell, network-drive

I'm creating a PowerShell script which will create a report of mapped network drive for particular user.
username should be provided as parameter to the script.
till now I've tried to use "net use" but it is only showing me the mapped drives for the user through which powershell is running.
is there any place where I can find the complete information about network drives for all the users.

Comment: I don't think so, the mapped drives are based on the current user. I don't think there is a way to get that information.

Comment: Drive mappings are stored in the registry (under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Network`, also accessible via `HKEY_USERS\<user sid>\Network`), so the user would need be logged on for you to access the information.  Alternatively, you can try loading the user's 'NTUSER.DAT' file from their profile and get it that way.

Comment: from what i can tell, you can do that two ways ... [1] check is as the user while the user is logged in - perhaps with a logon script or a scheduled task. ///// [2] load the user hive and get the info from there.

Comment: There is no way to get the information you want in the way you want. What you could do is set the ps that you already have as a task on their pcs and make it store the retrieved data on a common location. Then access the data from there.

Comment: @boxdog Thanks for your answer, it was helpful and now i'm able to fetch required information.